# npm run script invoking Rollup does nothing but open config file

Tags: npm, rollupjs, npm-scripts

We have a script `"build": "rollup -c rollup.js --environment production"`, which when called by some of our team (who use Windows) will on occasion spontaneously not run as normal, but  instead just open up the `rollup.js` config file in an editor. Unfortunately I don't really know where to start with this because I've never been able to replicate it. No logfile is being produced and as far as I've been told `ignore-scripts` is not set, which are the only other things I've seen related to this behaviour on SO.

Is this a known thing that there's a simple fix for? Or if not, where should I go to find more info about this? Would this be an issue with npm, or with rollup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some investigating I've tracked this down to what I believe to be a rollup bug with regards to how they're processing their config files. I feel as though I should open a ticket with them regarding this but I've been acting on behalf of a team member and don't have the ability to replicate it on my own, so... I suppose I'll try and coerce them into doing it.

But anyways, so from what I can tell looking at rollup's source, if a rollup config file has a plain `.js` extension, then it looks as though rollup is running itself on the config to convert it into a CommonJS format, which it will then import and use on the actual build step. Somewhere in this process on Windows something goes awry and the result is that the config file just ends up getting opened with whatever the default handler is for JS files. So basically the solution is to change the file extension.

Our original config was set up using ES6 import/export, and I'm unclear at this point whether changing the extension to `.mjs` will skip or otherwise change this conversion step, it seems to have worked as such when people have tried it but I can't vouch for it. What I did was to instead go through the config and manually convert all the ES6 import/exports to CommonJS `require()` and then change the file extension to `.cjs` (hence our config changed from `rollup.js` to `rollup.cjs`) and now it appears to be working consistently across the board.

Answer (score 0):

I encunter the same sutiation on Windows.

I bypass it by using WSL.